# Update values in pandas dataframe column if they exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have two dataframes, the first one has all the values, but some of them are old, while the second one has only some of the values, but they are new. What I would like to do is to update the values in the first dataframe with the values in the second dataframe, if they exist.

```
df_a
   A  B
0  a  1
1  b  2
2  c  3
3  d  4
4  e  5
5  f  6
6  g  7
7  h  8
8  i  9

df_b
   A  B
0  a  9
1  c  6
2  e  4
```

my desired result is:

```
df_a
   A  B
0  a  9
1  b  2
2  c  6
3  d  4
4  e  4
5  f  6
6  g  7
7  h  8
8  i  9
```

how do I accomplish this, hopefully without loops? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can construct a series via `set_index` and use `map` + `fillna` to update values:

```
s = df_b.set_index('A')['B']
df_a['B'] = df_a['A'].map(s).fillna(df_a['B']).astype(int)

print(df_a)

   A  B
0  a  9
1  b  2
2  c  6
3  d  4
4  e  4
5  f  6
6  g  7
7  h  8
8  i  9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are several ways it could be done

```
# options 1 and 2 use numpy
import numpy as np

# 1
# use numpy isin and numpy searchsorted functions
mask = np.isin(df_a.A, df_b.A)
df_a.B.values[mask] = \
    df_b.B.values[np.searchsorted(df_b.A.values,
                                  df_a.A.values[mask])]

# -----------------------------------------------------------------
# using pandas merge for next 3 methods:
merged = df_a.merge(df_b, on='A', how='outer',
                    suffixes=('_dfa', '_dfb'))

# 2
# use numpy where to fill in with df_a["B"] values
df_a['B'] = np.where(merged['B_dfb'].isnull(),
                     merged['B_dfa'],
                     merged['B_dfb']).astype(int)

# 3
# same as above but use pandas series where to fill values
df_a['B'] = merged.B_dfa.where(merged['B_dfb'].isnull(),
                               merged['B_dfb']).astype(int)

# 4
# use series fillna
df_a['B'] = merged['B_dfb'].fillna(merged['B_dfa']).astype(int)

#----------------------------------------------------------------
# for next 2 methods, make "A" column indexed
# dataframes from df_a, df_b
a = df_a.set_index('A')
b = df_b.set_index('A')

# 5
# using pandas dataframe update
a.update(b)
df_a['B'] = a['B'].values.astype(int)

# 6
# using pandas auto-align by index and pandas series where

# using pandas auto-align to index,
# add dataframe b "B" values to dataframe a (df_a indexed with column "A")
a['C'] = b['B']
# using pandas series where, fill in values from a["B"] and
# assign to df_a["B"]
df_a['B'] = a['C'].where(~a['C'].isnull(), a['B']).values.astype(int)
# or use pandas series fillna
df_a['B'] = a['C'].fillna(a['B']).values.astype(int)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------

# 7
# slightly modified version of accepted answer avoiding setting index
df_a['B'] = df_a['A'].map(dict(df_b.values)).fillna(df_a['B']).astype(int)
```